# How can i show a loader (Reactjs), while the slice in my store (Redux) is empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, to put you in context. In my project, I retrieve data from multiple API.The problem is that data take time to fully load. I did use setTimeout to solve the problem, But it's not the best solution.

Comment: You could easily track a `loading` state. Have it initialize as true, and in your `useEffect()` function, after your API data is consumed, set `loading` to false. In your component, wrap in `{ !loading && <Component> }`

Comment: Thank you for your response. So to clarify more the architecture of my project, to put it simply, I have `HomeScreen`, `Loader` (Many loaders), `Component`(Many Components). In my case, I consume data from the API in the  `Loader`, because as I said, I have many APIs. So to use, what you just said i need to consume data from the API in `HomeScreen` .

Comment: It's hard for me to say without seeing how you're implementing everything. Essentially, wherever you're using the loaders you can wrap in a loading variable. That way, you can conditionally show either a loading screen, or the data that's eventually returned. If you post something, I can show you what I mean. :)

Comment: you can use react-query for making requests and you will have a loading state out of the box, react-query is a great library and provides much more than that I think it will be good for your use case too, saying on the basis of whatever you have told so far. as @JoelHager said it would be easier for us to help if you post a relevant part of your code.